# Apache: 403 Forbidden when activate virtual host

Tags: apache, virtualhost

i have an absurd problem with apache and CentOS, the webserver work in default mode, when go to http://myip i view correctly the apache test page. If add `/etc/httpd/conf.d/foo.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.local
    DocumentRoot "/home/foo/html"

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/foo.local-error.log

    <Directory "/home/foo/html">
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have 403 forbidden to ALL directory configured to apache, i do not see either the test page.
The directory `/home/foo/html` have owner and group `apache`, and permission 775 to directory and 664 to file. I see in the log:

`AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/foo/html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path`

If i deactive this conf file, apache works and see the test page

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved changing the path, instead that `/home/foo/html` i put `/var/www/foo` and worked